# Unzip multiple files in multiple folders in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We have 3 different files.

1. Customer details
2. Product details
3. Sales details

We will get these files daily with folder name with date stamp. Inside the folder we will have zip files (`.gz`).

Customerdetails:

```
Folder1: 04012019_CustomerDetails --> ZipFile 
Folder2: 04022019_CustomerDetails --> ZipFile
```

I need to unzip the files and then save them in the same location. Can anyone please help me how to do this dynamically?

After unzipping the files I need to load all three different files into 3 different destinations:

1. Customer details
2. Product details
3. Sales details

Comment: What have you done so far? How far have you got? What isn't working? The best that people would be able to do at the moment is give you ideas; we need specifics to be able to give you a specific solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to process all zip files in different folders and then extract them into the same location. i am looking for suggestions how to do .

Comment: doable in SSIS.  There's plenty of tutorials around, probably not exactly your situation.   High level you're probably looking at for-each loop, then inside that a script task to unzip the files, then possible another nested for-each if the compressed files have multiples, then 3 different data flows to then load to each of the destinations.